# Alias + and - in zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh, alias, csh

For years I've used `+` and `-` as aliases for `pushd` and `popd` in both `csh` and `bash`. I've finally given up on my Macs and want to switch to `zsh` but I haven't been able to find a way to make these aliases. My fingers are pretty much trained to use these when navigating around from the command line. Help!

Comment: Ah - I had that in my alias list for `-` but it isn't needed for `+` in the other shells. Thanks! (Make it an answer and I'll gladly accept it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`--` to terminate option processing](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html):

```
alias -- +='pushd'
alias -- -='popd'
```

Comment: Or use `aliases[-]=pushd aliases[+]=popd`. Note that  `-` is already a (very rarely used) builtin in zsh.

Comment: Note  that you'd need `aliases[=]=...` to define an alias for `=`. In csh, aliases were defined with `alias name value`. It's unclear why  ksh decided to change it to `alias name=value` when they copied the feature in  the 80s. In zsh, alias and function names can be anything (though for aliases, not every name would be useful as only delimited tokens are subject to alias expansions), you could also do `-() pushd "$@"; +() popd "$@"`